# Property 'value' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>' when asserting using Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to assert the value of an input field:

```js
cy.get('[data-vv-name="item price"]')
    .then(response => {
        expect(response.value).to.be.equal('100')
    })
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'
```

But when I try the code to the console:

```
$('[data-vv-name="item price"]').value
```

I'm able to get the correct value of **'100'**.
What should I add/update to make my assertion correct? Am I missing anything here?

**EDIT**:

Using the following, I was able to do my assertion

```
expect((<HTMLInputElement>response[0]).value).to.be.equal(10)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery objects don't have `.value` property, but they do have `.val()` method that you could use

```js
cy.get('[data-vv-name="item price"]')
  .then($el => {
    // $el is convention for naming jQuery objects
    expect($el.val()).to.be.equal('100')
  })
```

or use `.invoke()` in the chain (ref [invoke](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/invoke#Usage))

```js
cy.get('[data-vv-name="item price"]')
  .invoke('val')
  .then(value => {
    expect(value).to.be.equal('100')
  })
  .should('eq', '100')    // alternative to above assertion
```

or you can use the `.should('have.value', ...)` chainer  (ref [should](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should#Rules))

```js
cy.get('[data-vv-name="item price"]')
  .should('have.value', '100')
```

or use the `.value` property of the unwrapped element as you have shown